# Laravel / Eloquent order Relationship Descending without Raw SQL?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to order by a relationship, so that the records in that relationship are discending without using raw SQL?

Example:

```
$device = CustomerDevice::with('user')->with('customerDeviceHistory')->find($did);
```

Entries in `customerDeviceHistory` should be descending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will order by id in desc order of `customerDeviceHistory` id.

```
$device = CustomerDevice::with('user')->with(['customerDeviceHistory'=>function($query)
    {
        $query->orderBy('id','desc');
    }
])->find($did);
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe, for example:

```
function customerDeviceHistory() {
   return $this->hasOne('App\[DeviceHistory]', 'id', 'deviceHistory_id')->orderBy('date', 'desc');
}
```

Add orderBy to relationship function

Comment: +++++++++++++++